# How to generate another solution $\in \mathbb N$ of $x^2=2y^2+7$ knowing one.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

This is from a new book I started reading; it asks whether I can construct another solution for $x^2=2y^2+7$, given that $(x_0,y_0)$ is one. It gives the following diagram as a hint:

[image]

However, this diagram only "tells me" that there are no integer solutions ($\neq 0$) for $x^2=2y^2$, and I really don't see how I can use that information. I wrote a little program to find the solutions up to 1000:

```
x | 3  5  13  27  75  157  437  915
y | 1  3   9  19  53  111  309  647
```

but cannot work out any patterns (except for all the numbers being odd). Any further hints would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** The table above is supposedly superfluous. I am really curious as to how the diagram constitutes a hint.

Here's the German excerpt:

> IV . Die Basis eines gleichschenkeligen rechtwinkligen Dreiecks sei $x$ und die Schenkellänge sei $y$.
>
> a) [...]
>
> b) Entwickle aus der Zeichnung ein Verfahren, aus einer Lösung $(x,y)$ der Gleichung $x^2-2y^2=7$ eine weitere zu erhalten.
>
> c) [...]

What might be relevant, is that in one of the previous examples it was shown, that if $(x_0,y_0)$ a soltion to $x^2+xy-y^2=1$, others can be obtained with $(y,x+y)$ and $(y-x,x)$, and that the same equation with a $0$ instead of a $1$ has no solutions.

Comment: Look for *Pell* Equation. Called that because the equation was studied almost a thousand years before Pell, by Brahmagupta and others. And, as far as is known, never studied by Pell. Let $(a,b)$ be a solution. Then $(u,v)$ will be a solution, where $u+v\sqrt{2}=(a+b\sqrt{2})(3+2\sqrt{2})^n$. From this you can get a recurrence.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That is very interesting, thank you! Can you think of a way to connect it to the diagram? This should be simpler judging from the surrounding tasks.

Comment: It reminds me of the geometric argument for generating solutions of $x^2-2y^2=1$ that I remember seeing, and indeed using before in a lecture. (It comes up in making rational approximations of $\sqrt{2}$.)  Am at this time too lazy to reconstruct.

Comment: I dk how the diagram is supposed to help. But 2 good answers so far..

Comment: @AndréNicolas Well, that's at least closer to $x^2-2y^2=0$ ^^

Comment: @user254665 It's weird, the tasks before and after I was able to solve in minutes.

Comment: Indeed we get close remarkably fast. Using $(3+2\sqrt{2})^2$ we get $17/12$. Squaring again we get $577408$, already excellent. Squaring again should get us well beyond calculator accuracy.

Comment: apparently it is not a hint, they are just saying that they will develop, possibly somewhere else in the book, the method they discuss, for which you have answers now. The book does not appear to have much about quadratic forms, maybe they have something in the direction Andre told you about.

Comment: try https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pellsche_Gleichung

Comment: @WillJagy I added something that might be useful. As to the figure: to me it's unambiguous that I have to develop the method using this triangle. Pell is way too advanced compared with the next few pages. Thank you for your engagement by the way.

Comment: Well, it's your language. The only thing that makes sense to me is that a triangle with two edges $x$ and one $y,$ such that $x^2 - 2 y^2 = 7,$ gets very close to a right triangle when $x$ and $y$ become large. You can calculate the angle with the Law of Cosines

Comment: Hold on, that could be it: the diagram is ***not*** a right triangle.

Comment: @WillJagy To be fair, there are no dots in the angles, but the big one is for sure 90° ("rechtwinkligen"). I'll remove the dot in the small one.

Comment: oh, well. the small angle probably is also, because the new edge is tangent to what seems to be a circular arc.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you have a solution $(x_0, y_0)$ for $x^2 = 2y^2 + 7$.  Now suppose you have another solution $(a_0, b_0)$ for $a^2 = 2b^2 + 1$.  Then because $$\begin{align*} 7 = (7)(1) &= (x^2-2y^2)(a^2-2b^2) \\ &= (ax)^2 - 2(bx)^2 - 2(ay)^2 + 4(by)^2 \\ &= (ax)^2 + 4(ax)(by) + 4(by)^2 - 2(bx)^2 - 2(ay)^2 - 4(bx)(ay) \\ &= (ax+2by)^2 - 2(ay+bx)^2, \end{align*}$$ we see that $$(x_1, y_1) = (a_0 x_0 + 2b_0 y_0, a_0 y_0 + b_0 x_0)$$ is also a solution to $x^2 = 2y^2 + 7$.  Now since $(a_0, b_0) = (3,2)$ is a fairly easy solution of the second identity, we get $$(x_1, y_1) = (3x_0 + 4y_0, 2x_0 + 3y_0)$$ is a solution if $(x_0, y_0)$ is a solution.

---

What is curious about this result is that it actually also finds additional solutions to the auxiliary equation $a^2 = 2b^2 + 1$, since our derivation did not rely on the fact that we had a $7$.  If that $7$ had been $1$, it still would have held, meaning that we could generate other solutions to $a^2 = 2b^2 + 1$ *using the same recursion formula*.  Indeed, we find $(a_1, b_1) = (17, 12)$ also works.

Furthermore, we can also see how to generalize the above for equations of the form $$x^2 = Dy^2 + N,$$ for square-free $D$ and positive integers $N$.  I leave it as an exercise for the reader to determine if such a method can be used to generate *all* integer solutions.

Answer (score 4):

given a solution $(x,y)$ of $$ x^2 - 2 y^2 = k, $$ you get a new solution with
$$ (3x+4y, 2x+3y) $$

The matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
3 & 4 \\
2 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
 and its inverse generate the (oriented) automorphism group of the quadratic form $x^2 - 2 y^2$

It should be noted that you must use two seed solutions to get your entire list, $(3,1)$ and $(3,-1).$ The two infinite sequences of pairs are interlaced in your list

By Cayley-Hamilton, we get a one-variable recurrence, however it applies to every other number;
$$ x_{2n+4} = 6 x_{2n+2} - x_{2n}  $$
$$ x_{2n+5} = 6 x_{2n+3} - x_{2n +1}  $$
$$ y_{2n+4} = 6 y_{2n+2} - y_{2n}  $$
$$ y_{2n+5} = 6 y_{2n+3} - y_{2n +1}  $$
For example, $6 \cdot 13 - 3 = 75,$  $6 \cdot 75 - 13 = 437.$

Comment: Is there a method to derive this? More specifically, to tie it to the diagram?

Comment: @Grantwalzer, several methods. What book are you talking about?

Comment: I mean, how is the diagram a hint? It's a German book, "Zahlentheorie für Einsteiger" by A. Bartholomé, J. Rung and H. Kern.

Comment: @Grantwalzer Found a preview online, more than half the pages, but the index is not shown. What page?

Comment: @Grantwalzer, so far it won't let me see that, although some other preview might eventually do so. It would help if you posted that page as an image in your question; definitely include the writing and symbols, not just that diagram. I know enough German to read a page of mathematics, also there are plenty of fluent German speakers on the site.

Comment: @Grantwalzer, yes, it would, also relevant writing and formulas from earlier pages.